Extra liftarm piece included in Airbus Helicopter 42145 set
So I just finished building set 42145 (Airbus Search & Rescue helicopter).
In the picture below you see the left-over "extra" pieces.

The usual assortment of 1x1 tiles, bushings and connector pins.
But that lift-arm piece?
I'm 100% certain it really is an extra. The build uses 6 of these and they are all in places were it is impossible to forget one without noticing that straight away.
This one was "left behind" when putting together stage 4 of the build.
I never have seen a extra lift-arm (or regular bricks larger than a 1x1) in any set and I must have build over a 100 by now.
Has anyone seen such a large brick as extra before or did I just get lucky?

You can easily verify they're actually included in the build : 4 should be immediately visible - 2 right above the cockpit, and 2 at the base of the rudder (affixing it to the tail boom). The final 2 form part of the internal structure of the tail boom (right next to the motor, covered by slanted panels saying "S.A.R." on the sides - you should be able to spot them from the bottom though without having to take it apart.

@SanderDeDycker All 6 are accounted for in the build. I double checked that. This is a real extra. I didn't mess up the build.

It is pretty much impossible to tell firmly if you built your model correctly without having an option to observe it in person.
Based on Bricklink's inventory for 42145 set liftarm/beam isn't the only extra "extra" piece you have. Your "extra" also includes:

1 x Technic, Axle 2L with Pin with Friction Ridges
1 x Technic, Axle Connector with Axle Hole
1 x Technic, Pin with Short Friction Ridges




As far as I know LEGO confirms the contents of the packages (during manufacturing) by weight. Extra parts you have on top what is expected to be as an "extra" are quite heavy, so I would expect them to be flagged and removed before packaging. I would suggest to double check if you haven't missed anything or substituted some parts.

One time I tried having an extra piece which was not even in the set. Not a giant one, but larger than those which are normally extra. However, another piece about the same size was missing. I assume that was why it slipped through the weight QA.

@Alex, why do you list the technic pin as erroneous extra? There are clearly two in the extra parts of bricklink

@MichaelVerschaeve pictures shows 3 of these pins, while BL lists only 2 as "extra".
